# Rails deployment to staging using capistrano generates the following error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git, capistrano3, rvm-capistrano

I get the following when I try to deploy to server using capistrano gem from my local machine(MAC)  {Rails app}. I am new to rails

```
user-mbp:xp user$ cap staging deploy
Server password:
********
DEBUG [c6110f69] Running /usr/bin/env [ -d ~/.rbenv ] as deployer@server.com
DEBUG [c6110f69] Command: [ -d ~/.rbenv ]
DEBUG [c6110f69] Finished in 6.956 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
INFO [e385c416] Running /usr/bin/env mkdir -p /tmp/pepe/ as deployer@server.com
DEBUG [e385c416] Command: ( RBENV_ROOT=~/.rbenv RBENV_VERSION=2.0.0-p353 /usr/bin/env mkdir -p /tmp/pepe/ )
INFO [e385c416] Finished in 0.098 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
DEBUG Uploading /tmp/pepe/git-ssh.sh 0.0%
INFO Uploading /tmp/pepe/git-ssh.sh 100.0%
INFO [191046c4] Running /usr/bin/env chmod +x /tmp/pepe/git-ssh.sh as deployer@server.com
DEBUG [191046c4] Command: ( RBENV_ROOT=~/.rbenv RBENV_VERSION=2.0.0-p353 /usr/bin/env chmod +x /tmp/pepe/git-ssh.sh )`enter code here`
INFO [191046c4] Finished in 0.119 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
INFO [bd99c2fc] Running /usr/bin/env git ls-remote --heads ssh://git@git.xxx.xx.com/xp.git as deployer@server.com
DEBUG [bd99c2fc] Command: ( RBENV_ROOT=~/.rbenv RBENV_VERSION=2.0.0-p353 GIT_ASKPASS=/bin/echo GIT_SSH=/tmp/pepe/git-ssh.sh /usr/bin/env git ls-remote --heads ssh://git@git.xxx.xx.com/xp.git )
DEBUG [bd99c2fc]    Permission denied (publickey,password).
DEBUG [bd99c2fc]    fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
(Backtrace restricted to imported tasks)
cap aborted!
SSHKit::Runner::ExecuteError: Exception while executing as deployer@server.com: git exit status: 128
git stdout: Nothing written
git stderr: Permission denied (publickey,password).
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly

SSHKit::Command::Failed: git exit status: 128
git stdout: Nothing written
git stderr: Permission denied (publickey,password).
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

I tried `git:check`, but still showing the same.

```
Tasks: TOP => git:check
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
The deploy has failed with an error: Exception while executing as deployer@server.com: git exit status: 128
git stdout: Nothing written
git stderr: Permission denied (publickey,password).
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

Staging.rb

```
# *************************************************************** #
require 'highline'

set :stage, :staging

set :password, HighLine.new.ask('Server password:') { |q| q.echo = '*'}
server 'xx.x.com', user: 'deployer', password: fetch(:password), roles: %w{web app db}, primary: true
set :test_url, 'https://xx.x.com'
set :version, `git describe --always`

# you can set custom ssh options
# it's possible to pass any option but you need to keep in mind that net/ssh understand limited list of options
# you can see them in [net/ssh documentation](http://net-ssh.github.io/net-ssh/classes/Net/SSH.html#method-c-start)
# set it globally
#  set :ssh_options, {
#    keys: %w(/home/rlisowski/.ssh/id_rsa),
#    forward_agent: false,
#    auth_methods: %w(password)
#  }
# and/or per server
# server 'example.com',
#   user: 'user_name',
#   roles: %w{web app},
#   ssh_options: {
#     user: 'user_name', # overrides user setting above
#     keys: %w(/home/user_name/.ssh/id_rsa),
#     forward_agent: false,
#     auth_methods: %w(publickey password)
#     # password: 'please use keys'
#   }
# setting per server overrides global ssh_options

# fetch(:default_env).merge!(rails_env: :staging)
```

Comment: I assume that you deploy from your developing machine. And from your developing machine you also push to git. This means you have your git credentials on your development machine. You can forward these when you add `set :ssh_options, :forward_agent => true` to your config/deploy/staging.rb. If that doesn't help it would be good if you could post your staging.rb file.

Comment: hi @sugaryourcoffee posted the staging.rb file

Comment: Did you check whether your public key at the repository matches your private key on your deployment machine? The error is indicating that this is not the case. If you are on Github then you can check from your deployment machine whether you can access your repository with `ssh -vT git@github.com`.

Comment: @sugaryourcoffee i have logged into the server and found .ssh  directory where it has Known_hosts only.whereas my local machine has github_rsa.pub and id_rsa.pub and known_hosts. Is this the reason for  error??

Comment: @sugaryourcoffee this is what i get when i try ssh -vT git@github.com  ,,, 
OpenSSH_6.2p2, OSSLShim 0.9.8r 8 Dec 2011
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh_config line 20: Applying options for *
ssh: Could not resolve hostname git.xx.x.com/xp.git: nodename nor servname provided, or not known

Comment: O.k. I will post further information in the answer section to give you some more information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two possible solutions

1. Copy your private key to your deployment machine
   As you can push to Github (this is what I understand) you have a private key on your development machine and the corresponding public key on Github. You can copy your private key onto your deployment machine to get rid of the error

   develeopment-machine$ scp ~/.ssh/id-rsa.pub deployment-machine:key

Then ssh to your deployment machine and do

```
deployment-machine$ mv ~/.ssh/id-rsa.pub ~/.ssh/id-rsa.old
deployment-machine$ mv ~/key ~/.ssh/id-rsa.pub
```

2. Create a key on your deployment machine and add public key to Github
   There is a easy to follow explanation how to do that at [Github Help](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys/)

Hope this helps.

Links to projects using Capistrano

If you are on Rails 3:

- [capfile](https://github.com/sugaryourcoffee/secondhand/blob/master/Capfile)
- [deploy.rb](https://github.com/sugaryourcoffee/secondhand/blob/master/config/deploy.rb)
- [environments](https://github.com/sugaryourcoffee/secondhand/tree/master/config/deploy)
- [development notebook](https://github.com/sugaryourcoffee/secondhand/blob/master/doc/deployment.md)

If you are on Rails 4:

- [capfile](https://github.com/sugaryourcoffee/apptrack/blob/master/Capfile)
- [deploy.rb](https://github.com/sugaryourcoffee/apptrack/blob/master/config/deploy.rb)
- [environments](https://github.com/sugaryourcoffee/apptrack/tree/master/config/deploy)
- [development notebook](https://github.com/sugaryourcoffee/apptrack/blob/master/doc/deployment.md)

Comment: i think the reason for the error is my local machine is pointed towards a particular git to which i commit and push,whereas the servers(both production and staging) are pointing to another git repo.i checked it using git remote -v command.what should i do to resolve it?

Comment: set the repository in your staging configuration file to the repository you push your code to like `set :repository,  "git@github.com:git_user/git_application.git"`

Comment: still have the same issue.i am in crisis with this stuff.Is there any way to solve this and deploy to the staging server from my local machine

Comment: i have changed as you said in staging.rb file but it still the same

Comment: Actually to your particular problem I am out of ideas. What I can offer is a working example of a project of mine. I will put links to my answer.

Comment: should i uncomment the ssh options in the staging.rb file??

Comment: Yes you could give it a try. But the problem is with your key on github. If your repository is on github and you use the same key as on your development machine (the machine where you push your code from), then you should also try `forward_agent: true`.